Example of properly used autoreleasepool in Swift
Are there any examples of autoreleasepool usage in Swift?
I don't mean examples which illustrate how auto-releasing works, but examples which show how auto-releasing really increases performance or memory usage.
I found examples like this:
for _ in 1...1000 {
    autoreleasepool {
        // Create and use temporary objects here
        let tempObject = SomeClass()
        // ...
    }
    // tempObject is released at the end of each iteration
}

However, as I understand, tempObjects are destroyed at the end of each iteration anyway, without using autoreleasepool.

Also see this discussion on forums.swift.org
